# Log file location based on hostname with syslog-ng

Tags: linux, syslog

I'm using syslog-ng for a big amount of servers. To get everything more in shape in the folder structure, I use several filters with regex and multiple destination and log lines in the syslog-ng.conf

What I would like to accomplish is to let syslog decide where to put the log file based on parts of the hostname and put it in 1 filter, with 1 destination and log line.

Example:

```
fl-app-dev-01   =>   /var/log/fl/dev/app01.log
fl-app-prd-32   =>   /var/log/fl/prd/app32.log
fl-man-prd-02   =>   /var/log/fl/prd/man02.log
am-app-prd-12   =>   /var/log/am/prd/app12.log
rd-app-dev-02   =>   /var/log/rd/dev/app02.log
```

As you can see in the example above, all servers are in the same format
{location}-{function}-{environment}-{number}

I would like to split them to location, then to environment and have the logfile named after the function and the server number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to achieve this, you must parse the hostname and split it to separate fields using a csv-parser, then use the fieldnames as macros in your destination file template. See the second example here: [Segmenting hostnames in syslog-ng](https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/csv-parser.html)

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to accept the question. I totally forgot about it ;-)